# Object array NullPointerException, Processing 3.3.6

Tags: java, arrays, object, nullpointerexception, processing

I'm trying to make a simple 3d game in Processing but I've run into a problem.
I tried to make an array to keep track of my environment objects and to make it easier to modify. However, when I try to run the program, it won't work.

Main code:

```
  //arrays
BoxCl[] envArr;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360, P3D);

  envArr[0] = new BoxCl(1,1,-1,1);              //it shows the error here
  envArr[envArr.length] = new BoxCl(2,1,-1,1);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  camera(mouseX, height/2, (height/2) / tan(PI/6), width/2, height/2, 0, 0, 1, 0);
  Update();
  Draw();
}

void Update(){

}

void Draw(){
  for(BoxCl i : envArr){
    i.Draw();
  }
}
```

BoxCl Class:

```
class BoxCl{

  float x, y, z;
  int s;

  BoxCl(float x, float y, float z, int size){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
    this.s = size;
  }

  void Draw(){
    translate(scale*x, scale*y, scale*z);
    stroke(255);
    fill(255);
    box(s * scale);
    translate(scale*-x, scale*-y, scale*-z);
  }

}
```

I've tried looking it up ([here for example](https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/8071/why-do-i-get-a-nullpointerexception)) but I think I'm too inexperienced to understand what I am supposed to do.

Please help.

edit: I am aware that a variable/array/object should be defined before being used. But how do I define the envArr in a way that it can still change? (i.e. increase or decrease in size when I have to create or delete an object)

Comment: TL;DR: you never initialized the array `envArr`

Comment: Your edit should be posted as a separate question with a new [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `envArr` variable is `null`. You have to initialize it to something before you use it.

You probably want something like this:

```
BoxCl[] envArr = new BoxCl[10];
```

Shameless self-promotion: I wrote a tutorial on arrays in Processing available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/arrays). You should also get into the habit of [debugging your code](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) by adding `println()` statements or stepping through your code with the debugger. For example, if you had printed out the value of `envArr` before the line that throws the error, you would have seen for yourself that it was `null`.

Comment: What do I do when I don't know the final size of the array though? Because in this case, it restricts the amount of objects than can/have to be used.

Comment: @Mr.Dude__ Don't use array, use `ArrayList<BoxCl>` if you don't know how long can it grow

Comment: @Mr.Dude__ You can use Processing's `append()` function. More info in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/append_.html). Or better yet, use an `ArrayList`. [Here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/arraylists) is a tutorial on ArrayLists in Processing.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Thanks, it's all working now. I used your Arraylist tutorial and it's running smoothly. Nice site btw :)